# How do I make my Nexus 5 work with ADB on my Windows 7 desktop?

Tags: usb-debugging, nexus-5

I am attempting to develop on the Nexus 5 using the Android SDK on eclipse.

I'm developing on Windows 7, have the Helios version of Eclipse, and have kept my SDK up to date. I have previously been developing on a Samsung Galaxy S2 fine - but now the SDK is having trouble detecting the Nexus 5.

I have developer options, usb debugging, and third party apk's all enabled on the phone. When connecting the phone it appears as an eject-able USB device, appears as "Nexus 5" under Unspecified in devices and printers, and appears as "Android Composite ADB Interface" under "SAMSUNG Android Phone" in device manager.

I have tried uninstalling the usb drivers I was using with the galaxy (including kies - its additional software) and then reinstalling drivers through the SDK manager, I have tried modifying the drivers as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838016/what-usb-driver-should-we-use-for-the-nexus-5 and I have tried to install the generic driver here: http://adbdriver.com/downloads/ (but this failed as it could not find the nexus 5 as a connected android device). I've also tried simple things such as restarting eclipse, the phone, and my machine, and trying different USB ports. None of this has helped, I am unable to browse the nexus 5 as removable storage and when running projects in eclipse it does not appear as a running android device.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the Nexus 5 think it's plugged in? Do you get the "Connected as a media device" and "USB debugging connected" notifications?

Comment: Yes - I get both of those notifications.

Its also worth noting the machine also picks up the Nexus 5 in a sense - as I mention above it appears in both the device manager and under printers and devices in the control panel. However it does not appear to be properly detected as a connected android device as it does not appear in the SDK's run dialogue nor as a browse-able storage under Removable Storage.

Comment: Figured it out myself. While I had uninstalled the previous drivers through the control panel, and uninstalled through the device manager what I needed to do was uninstall through the device manager and check the delete check box before reinstalling. All works fine now.

Comment: Please post that as an answer, and accept it so that other visitors can see what the solution was.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out myself. While I had uninstalled the previous drivers through the control panel, and uninstalled through the device manager what I needed to do was uninstall through the device manager and check the delete check box before reinstalling. All works fine now.